# Where is PYTHONPATH added?

Tags: python, ubuntu, environment-variables

when I checked the PYTHONPATH with

```
echo $PYTHONPATH
```

The results are so complicated. I want to remove some lines. However, it s not in the bashrc, profile, or environment file.
Is there any way to fix this problem?

Results are:

```
/home/../carla-ros-bridge/install/rqt_carla_control/lib/python3.8/site-packages:/home/../carla-ros-bridge/install/carla_waypoint_publisher/lib/python3.8/site-packages:/home/../carla-ros-bridge/install/carla_ackermann_control/lib/python3.8/site-packages:/home/../carla-ros-bridge/install/carla_ros_bridge/lib/python3.8/site-packages:/home/../carla-ros-bridge/install/carla_spawn_objects/lib/python3.8/site-packages:/home/../carla-ros-bridge/install/carla_manual_control/lib/python3.8/site-packages:/home/../carla-ros-bridge/install/carla_ad_agent/lib/python3.8/site-packages:
```

and, it goes more on that. some lines repeat. I set this env with `export PYTHONPATH=...`

Comment: With this information I think we cannot know where your path is pointing, since we don´t know what commands have you used before this point. Anyways, linux libraries and dependencies usually live in /usr/bin/app_we_look_for/bin. If you are really concerned about it, uninstalling and reinstalling python should clean this messed path. Then you can place your pythonpath in ~/.bashrc file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html) with the `-E` option for the `python` binary all `PYTHON*` environment variables are ignored. The `PYTHONPATH` is set at runtime of your script as per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH). This variable should not be needed to be manually messed with.